# How can I measure how much CPU and RAM has been used by a command?

Tags: command-line, ram, cpu-load

I'm trying to measure the memory of a process that I call via the command line (i.e., I want to find out much CPU/RAM the process takes). Is there any command that I can add to the command calling the process that will achieve this?

Comment: simple answser is htop, isntall it by `sudo apt-get install htop` btw this is a dupe of a question just haven't got the time to find it now...

Answer (score 9):

## `top`

Example of firefox. Find the PID:

```
ps -aux | grep -i firefox
```

Then you can use `top -p pid`:

```
top -p  3845
```

[image]

---

## `ps`

You can also use `ps` command, **firefox pid is 3845**

```
$ ps -p 3845 -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
%CPU  %MEM CMD
11.1  3.7 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

---

I am not satisfied with the above mentioned commands, and I found something that you should be interested in.

## Monit

```
sudo apt-get install monit -y
```

Edit the Monit Config File

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Enable the web interface

```
set httpd port 2812
# use address localhost # only accept connection from localhost
allow localhost # allow localhost to connect to the server and
# allow 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 # allow any host on 192.168.1.* subnet
allow admin:monit # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
```

Checking process every 2 secons

```
## Start Monit in the background (run as a daemon):
set daemon 120 to only 2  # check process every 2 sec
```

**Example Firefox**

In the end copy paste the following command

```
check process firefox
matching "firefox"
```

**Save and Exit**

**Check your syntax**

Fix any problems found – it’s not too tough to figure out what’s going on.

```
sudo monit -t
```

**Start (or restart) Monit**

```
sudo service monit start
```

**Visit the web interface**

`http://localhost:2812` if you’re running Ubuntu Desktop, or

Sign in with your `admin:monit` credentials

> [image]

### Click on Firefox

> [image]

Related:

- [How to Install Monit](http://ghosttx.com/2012/03/how-to-install-monit-on-ubuntu-11-10-server-to-monitor-apache-web-server-mysql-ssh/)
- [Monit: check process without pidfile](https://serverfault.com/questions/270316/monit-check-process-without-pidfile)
- [Monit FAQ](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ)
- [Real-world Monit configuration examples](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples)
- [How can I get the CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux (Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt)

**You can also use these links for help and modify your process.**

---

## UPDATE

You can also configure an alert if firefox uses more than 250 MB of ram

```
check process firefox
matching "firefox"
if totalmem > 250.0 MB for 1 cycles then alert
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

You can also execute command

```
if totalmem > 250.0 MB for 1 cycles then exec "path to script"
```

You can also make a script of **Notify-Send**

```
/usr/bin/notify-send firefox "More Than 250 MB OF RAM"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The GNU time command can print the maximum resident set size used by a command. 
You do have to make sure to use the `/usr/bin/time` command, not the Bash Shell built-in `time` keyword.

For an example to measure the *firefox* command:

```
/usr/bin/time --format="Size:%MK  Cpu:%P  Elapsed:%e" firefox &
```

After using firefox a while, I close it out to get the report:

```
Size:168644K  Cpu:30%  Elapsed:226.34
```

While it is possible to use the TIME environment variable to set the default format I've found it more flexible to set up individual bash aliases with specific formats. So for the above I would add to my `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias ztm="/usr/bin/time --format=\"Size:%MK  Cpu:%P  Elapsed:%e\""
```

So that from my Bash Shell I could just enter:

```
ztm firefox &
```

References:

- [`man time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/time.1)
- `info time`
- [`man 2 getrusage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/getrusage.2) # - Shows which measures are available on Linux, the others show as zero