# How can I see the total memory used by, for example, google and firefox processes?

Tags: top, ps

top and ps show multiple processes for these applications. Is there a simple command to show only one entry for each application showing the total?

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [How can I measure how much CPU and RAM has been used by a command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292276/how-can-i-measure-how-much-cpu-and-ram-has-been-used-by-a-command).

Any suggestion using the pid of the process is not suitable because we have many processes associated with the application. For example:

```
ps aux | grep -i chrome | awk '{print $2}'
11288
27410
28415
28477
30396
30592
30602
30614
30617
30657
30842
30870
30875
30876
```

I am looking for something that will sum the usage by these processes while compensating for any memory that is shared between them -- if that is the case.

Comment: I have edited the question.